# How do you log into Amazon Web Services if you lose your phone which has Google 2-factor authentication set up?

Tags: authentication, google, iphone, amazon

And if it is possible, how do you prevent other people from claiming they are you and lost their phone?

Amazon only directs you to a page which does not exist.
http://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/

> If the authentication device associated with the AWS account is
>   damaged, lost, stolen, or stops working, you will need to contact us (http://aws.amazon.com/foms/aws-mfa-support/)
>   for help with disabling AWS MFA for the account. This will allow you
>   to temporarily sign in to AWS using just the user name and password
>   for the AWS account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fix the typo in the url

> https://aws.amazon.com/forms/aws-mfa-support/

(notice the 'r' in 'forms' that was previously missing

Comment: Oh... they actually linked to the typo though. Wouldn't a hacker be able to bypass the code with a little social engineering if they knew your phone number?

Comment: Since you found the typo, you might be a good citizen and let them know.  Regarding social engineering, I don't know their full process to authenticate you before disabling MFA so I don't know what the risks are or how they are mitigated. If you are really interested, try to learn it and analyze it for flaws, then report those flaws to AWS.